# How can I limit horizontally the space for the chapter title?

Tags: chapters, titles, size

I'm using titleformat to format my chapter titles. For example, I have:

```
\colorlet{chapnumcol}{NavyBlue!75}  % color for chapter number

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\filleft\bfseries}
{\filleft\textcolor{chapnumcol}{\thechapter}}
{-15pt}
{\Huge}
```

Then, in each page with the chapter I add a vertical image to the left using \AddToShipoutPictureBG*. My problem is that if the title of the chapter is long enough, the title will be over the image. I'd like to reduce the horizontal space avalaible for each chapter title, as if it were in a minipage. Is it possible to do this? How can I apply the same size for all the chapters (or for a specific one)?

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved. If you want to change chapter per chapter, just copy it again before the chapter and change it. Otherwise just put it before the first chapter only once.

```
\colorlet{chapnumcol}{NavyBlue!75}  % color for chapter number

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\filleft\bfseries}
{\filleft\textcolor{chapnumcol}{\thechapter}}
{-15pt}
{\hspace*{4.2cm}\begin{minipage}{8.5cm} \Huge}[\end{minipage}\vspace*{-4cm}]
```